# boolean logic in ruby 'true and false == true'

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

```
> test = false and true
=> false
> test
=> false
> test = true and false #this is the point I don't understand!
=> false
> test
=> true
```

Why does ruby behave in this way and how would I use it correctly to not run into this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Precedence.  `test = true and false` means this:

```
(test = true) and false
```

not this:

```
test = (true and false)
```

Use parentheses as above, or `&&` instead of `and`, if you want the assignment to come last:

```
test = true && false
```

Comment: From the github ruby styleguide : 'The and and or keywords are banned. It's just not worth it. Always use && and || instead.'

Comment: Inherited from Perl.  In the beginning, there was only `&&` and `||`.  But these were used both like C (as logical primtives) and like the shell (to handle success/failure).  In the latter use the precedence caused surprises like `my @info = stat($file) || die "error"` calling `stat` in scalar instead of list context. The lower-precedence `and`/`or`/`not` were introduced to solve those headaches, but gave us new ones, and Ruby borrowed them right along with the rest of the stuff it got from Perl.