# Preferred way to write true AND false conditional in Ruby

Tags: ruby, coding-style, logic

I apologize if this question is answered somewhere but I'm not positive I'm phrasing it right for Google, and I haven't seen it in any style guides.

Since Ruby has multiple ways to show negativity in a conditional, what is the preferred way to  write a conditional that is checking that one part is true and one part is false? Example:

```
if array && !array.include?('Bob')
  #do stuff!
```

But you could also say:

```
if array
  #do stuff! unless array.include?('Bob')
```

or:

```
if array && not array.include?('Bob')
  #do stuff
```

or:

```
if !array.nil? && !array.include?('Bob')
```

or a wacky double unless:

```
unless array.nil?
  #do stuff unless array.include?('Bob')
```

And several others. Any idea which is considered the most Rubyish? Sources to back your opinion up?

Comment: Do whatever is the most readable in the given context, with the caveat that "readable" is often a matter of preference.

Comment: Note that the [precedence of `!` and `not` are not the same](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) (like [`&&`/`||` & `and`/`or`](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)), and while I don't believe it makes a difference in your example, it's worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as documented guidelines, the only thing that i can think of is the Google guide that admonishes "don't use `and` and `or`; always use `&&` and `||` instead.".

Other than that, it somewhat depends on the context.  If all you have is code to be executed if one condition is true and the other false, then I would definitely put them in a single if with `&& !`:

```
if array && !array.include?('Bob')
  #do stuff!
```

On the other hand, you might have additonal code that gets executed if the first condition is true even if the second one is also true; in that case, the nested `unless` or `if` makes sense:

```
if array 
    do stuff! unless array.include? 'Bob'
    do other stuff anyway
end
```

Comment: I think the whole "don't use `and`/`or` ever" dogma is absurd. Instead, [know what they do](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) and use them when they make sense, as would be done with any other language feature.

Comment: I tend to agree, @AndrewMarshall.  I was just referencing the only vaguely-relevant Ruby style documentation I could think of, which was fresh in my mind because the precedence issue [recently confused someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249164/boolean-logic-in-ruby-true-and-false-true/10249213#10249213).

Comment: You make a good point about the additional code, @MarkReed, but I was specifically thinking of the one line example. In your case the presence of additional code helps shape a more logical flow, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Does not improve readability, but still interesting.

If you use Rails you can use ActiveSupport [`try`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) extension like this:

```
if array.try(:include?, 'Bob')
  # Do stuff
```

Comment: Rails specific too. Mine is a local Ruby script, but I'll make note of this for any rails projects I tackle.